# Why does Xcode always have trouble submitting archives to iTunes?

Tags: performance, xcode, app-store-connect

### Some Background

Xcode not submitting to iTunes flawlessly has ALWAYS plagued me! I just don't understand what's going on, ever!

I know what I am doing, I have quite a few apps in the iTunes App Store and Mac App Store. I know it's just buggy software because these issues didn't start happening until Xcode v4.0.

I **Archive** my application on **iOS Device** *or Release mode* and when Organizer appears, I login choosing the correct developer team, correct version and correct certificates. I also Validate my applications first and fore-most and always receive "Passed Validation" with no problem.

*My applications also never build with any issues or warnings.*

Most of the time, Xcode will just sit there and hang for a while on **Your application is being uploaded**. It's a 5/50 chance I'll get either of the 2 screens below.

[image]

Sometimes it will just sit here and animate and do nothing, even after about 10 minutes.

[image]

Sometimes the progress bar will get to about 10% (*more or less*), then other times it will get to around 80 - 90% (*guestimate*).

I have experienced extreme wait times with 2 applications I have done that have been over 300MB's which is understandable because there is a lot of data to upload.

But what I don't understand is why this same thing happens with, for instance my current application, which is around 15MB's archived.

Xcode seems to be very spotty and only seems to work some of the time and I have no clue why.

### Question

**Has anyone else experienced what I have mentioned above? If so, have you been able to narrow the issues down? And is there anything I can do differently to ensure that I have 100% successful submissions in the future?**

Answer (score 4):

Just waited for some hours and suddenly received the "No issues found. Passed validation. Has been submitted." notification. Very strange, but true.

Must have someting to do with current numbers of uploads to the store.